# Can someone explain WebKit?

Tags: webkit

I am trying to understand WebKit properly. I understand its the browser engine. But its not clear to me what exactly it contains and more importantly what does it not contain? The one thing I am having trouble placing is the JS engine. Is the DOM implementation part of WebKit?

Where does the JS engine (like V8) fit? Going by [this page](https://www.webkit.org/blog/1188/how-webkit-loads-a-web-page/) I assume that the SubResourceLoader towards the end of the image is loading the JS. But the JS also changes the DOM (or uses the DOM) so it needs to be integral part of the WebKit engine.

So can some one explain what WebKit does and more importantly what it does not do?

Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT: I found [this document](https://docs.google.com/presentation/pub?id=1ZRIQbUKw9Tf077odCh66OrrwRIVNLvI_nhLm2Gi__F0#slide=id.p) which explains all I need very clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the documentation?  [This part](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/SourceDirectory) describes the various components.

Also, Paul Irish wrote [a decent overview](http://paulirish.com/2013/webkit-for-developers/) that you should read.

Comment: This is great. I will go through it.